# OpenCV: Contours hidden behind mask. How to detect when a contour is about to move near mask edge?

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, computer-vision, edges

### Summary of Question

I am detecting object silhouettes in front of a light source.  To simplify the background and remove noise, I require masking everything that isn't the light source.  How can I tell when the object would be on the edge of the masked area?

### Assumptions

Assume featureless (monochrome black and white for edge detection) and ambiguous (a square in image 1 may be a circle in image 2) in shape.

### Detailed Explanation of the Problem with "High Quality" Figures

Consider a silhouette in front of a light source.  It is distinct and we can tell it is nested within the outer contour. Figure 1 depicts a simplified case.

[image: Distinct Contour]

We can treat our outer circle as a mask in this case, and easily ignore everything NOT within the contour.  Figure 2 depicts the simplified case with some edge detection.

[image: Contours are nice and simple here. Huzzah.]

Everything works lovely until the silhouette moves to the edge of the light source.  Suddenly we run into problems.  Figure 3 is an example of a shape on the edge.

[image: A silhouette is indistinguishable from the mask.]

The silhouette is indistinguishable from the black of the background/masked area.  OpenCV either assumes that suddenly the contour of our light source is funny shaped and there is no other object to be detected.

### The Question Restated

What tools can I use to detect that there has been some sort of interruption of the edge shape?  Is there a good/computational cheap way of determining if our silhouette is intersecting with another?

### Graveyard of What I Know Does NOT Work

- Assuming a static or simple silhouette shape.  The figures are cartoons representing a more complicated real problem.
- Assuming a perfectly round light source.  `HoughCircles` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cv2.log_polar` function to unwrap the circle/oval shape.

[image: log_polar]

After that, `np.argmax` can be used to find the curve. Try smoothing out the curve using Scipy's `signal.savgol_filter()`. When the object blocks the light source, there will be a big difference between the smoothed line and the argmax data:
[image: graph]

This is the code that I used:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
# Read the image
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/JkgJw.png', 0)
# Find the log_polar image
log_polar = cv2.logPolar(img, (img.shape[0]/2, img.shape[1]/2), 40, cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
# Create a background to draw on
bg = np.zeros_like(log_polar)
# Iterate through each row in the image and get the points on the edge
h,w = img.shape
points = []
for col in range(h-1):
    col_slice = log_polar[col:col+1, :]
    curve = np.argmax(255-col_slice)
    cv2.circle(bg, (curve, col), 0, 255, 1)
    points.append((curve, col))

cv2.imshow('log_polar', log_polar)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


import scipy
from scipy import signal

x,y = zip(*points)
x_smooth = signal.savgol_filter(x,123,2)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(x_smooth)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a useful answer because it brings up a CV2 function I was not aware of, although I am having trouble implementing for the "real" problem that is a bit more complicated than the simple model in the OP question.  I am currently playing with it.  How did you come up with a Magnitude of 40 in the logPolar function?

Comment: @WesH You should check out the OpenCV samples (run `demo.py`). That's where I learned about `cv2.logPolar`.  I used the same `magnitude` value as the sample `logPolar.py`.

Comment: It looks like the secret sauce is that the image needs to be near to square.  Adding a line: `img = img[0:img.shape[0], int((img.shape[1]-img.shape[0])/2):int(img.shape[1]-((img.shape[1]-img.shape[0])/2))]` helps a great deal.